# Paperclip configuration with Amazon S3 for rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I wanted to use Paperclip in my rails project which i have deployed in AWS. I'm needed some details on Paperclip with Amazon S3 configuration.

Specific to aws.yml , production.rb , development.rb

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can find info [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3), [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) and [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)

Answer (score 0):

I did this for learning purpose on development, what I did is as follows.

In development.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

in config/initislizer/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
            Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
            Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

and created a config/aws.yml with

```
access_key_id: '####################'
secret_access_key: '####################'
bucket: 'bucket-name'
```

and it worked well

**Note: you can surely handle keys in better way i.e envirnment variable**